Gitlab pipeline does not have pip installed
I have a gitlab pipeline split in two jobs but unfortunately the second job complains /bin/sh: eval: pip: not found.
Below is the .gitlab-ci.yml file.
stages:
  - build
  - test

default:
  image: docker:24.0
  
build_image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build .

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - pip install .[dev]
    - pytest

The build_image job is doing a build on my Dockerfile but despite that the next job does not find pip. The contents of the Dockerfile looks as follows:
FROM python:3.12-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/template_repository
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

How can I get the test job to find pip and install all the requirements?

You are installing pip inside the docker and running the pip install . Dev command outside of docker in git machine

@NoobCoder doesn't a default image mean, it would be shared between all jobs?

You are confusing a couple of concepts about how Gitlab jobs work.
1) Each job you run is independent.
Each job will look at it's settings (possibly pulling from default if not set) and use that to launch a fresh new job.  This makes sense when you consider that Gitlab jobs typically run in their own container and can be run on different hosts that share nothing.
stages:
  - build
  - test

default:
  image: docker:24.0
  
# This job pulls image docker:24.0 as it's starting point
build_image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build .

# This job ALSO pulls image docker:24.0 as it's starting point    
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - pip install .[dev]
    - pytest

2) To use an image you build, you need to publish it and specify it in the job
If you want to use your own image as the base image for a job, you'll need to publish it somewhere.
stages:
  - build
  - test

# publish to your gitlab after build 
build_image:
  stage: build
  image: docker:24.0
  script:
    - docker build . -t docker build -t yourgitlab.com/group/project/image
    - docker push yourgitlab.com/group/project/image

# use the image by setting image tag
test:
  stage: test
  image: yourgitlab.com/group/project/image
  script:
    - pip install .[dev]
    - pytest

3) If you just want to build your code in the job, and not explicitly build an image, just do that
If you just want to run tests, you don't really need to build a docker image.  You can just use existing ones and install what you need.  You can also share setup logic using before scripts in Gitlab jobs.  In the below example both test_pytest and test_pylint jobs are independent jobs that run the same setup steps when the jobs are run.
stages:
  - test

default:
  image: python3.10
  before_script:
    - pip install .[dev]

test_pytest:
  stage: test
  script:
    - pytest

test_pylint:
  stage: test
  script:
    - pylint


Thank you. I guess my organisation already had an image with which I was able to use. I confused myself on how image works in Gitlab pipeline.

This means that the base image you are using for running your jobs (the docker image) does not have pip installed.
To use a different image in the test job, you should use the image directive, for example:
test:
  stage: test
  image: python:3.12-slim
  script:
    - pip install .[dev]
    - pytest

I don't know what you are doing, but I think you are confusing concepts, as far as I know, it is not possible/good practice to build an image and use it as a base for the next job. You could try to build an image, push it to the gitlab registry, and then use it in your jobs.

Yes, it seems I had a confusion. I assumed that making changes to an image in one job would be available for another job too, but it's not. You first need to push it to registry and then use it further.
